# How to exclude zeroes for ggplot2 geom_line function in R in Power Bi

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi

I have a R visual in power bi. I use this visual to show a scatter plot with points(geom_point) and lines (geom_line).
The data (`Matlab_min_head - Matlab_max_head - Matlab`) used for the lines has a lot of unused zeroes in it which I would like to omit as the line will shows a dip.
How can I exlude the zeroes?
I'm not an expert in R, but I understand for power Bi the adjustment of the data should happen as the graph is build. I cannot filter my data beforehad and then plot the result.

The slightly simplified code (without all the formatting) is as follows:

```
Plot1<-ggplot(dataset, aes(x=Capacity_recalculated, y=Head_recalculated))
Plot1<-Plot1+geom_point(aes(colour=Head_recalculated))
#these are the 3 black lines:
Plot1<-Plot1+geom_line(aes(y=Matlab_min_head, x=Matlab_min_Q)) 
Plot1<-Plot1+geom_line(aes(y=Matlab_max_head,x=Matlab_max_Q))
Plot1<-Plot1+geom_line(aes(y=Matlab_head, x=Matlab_Q))
Plot1
```

[image: This is the graph I made using geom_line, you can see the dip]

---

Update:

So I educated myself on how to use subset after [Ismail's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55290282/11240063).
I think I know where the problem lies:
My data looks like this:

```
Project:         Head_recalculated: Matlab_min_head: Matlab_head:
1                10                 0                0
1                20                 0                0
...
Matlab           60                 0                60
Matlab           70                 0                70
......
Matlab_min_head  50                 50               0
Matlab_min_head  60                 60               0
......
```

So if I filter using:

```
Plot1<-ggplot(subset(dataset, Matlab_head>0)
```

or

```
Plot1<-ggplot(subset(dataset, Matlab_head !=0)
```

I essentially remove the other `Matlab_min_head` column and the other `Project` data from the dataset as it is 0.
Would there be an option to only let the subset remove values in the `Matlab_head` column (and not the complete dataset)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply remove the zeroes with `subset(dataset, Head_recalculated != 0)` in your first `ggplot` call:

`Plot1 <- ggplot(subset(dataset,Head_recalculated != 0), aes(x=Capacity_recalculated, y=Head_recalculated))`

Comment: This works for the zeroes in 'Head_recalculated', however I want to remove them from `Matlab_min_head`, `Matlab_max_head` and `Matlab_head`. If I replace `Head_recalculated` in the subset to `Matlab_min_head`, I do get the right line but it will remove all other lines

Comment: Hi Dude, maybe you could redo the `subset` operation within each `geom_line()` call. Otherwise it's better if you provide us a glimpse at your data's structure.

Comment: Hi Ismail, I updated my question and added some insight in my data. Adding the `subset` operation to the `geom_line` call gave an error.

Comment: Even if you try `geom_line(data = subset(dataset, Matlab_min_head != 0), aes(...))` ?